# iOS: Nested Scroll Views, switch from child UIScrollView to parent mid scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a tableview which contains cells that are full screen (fullScreenTableView with a fullScreenTableViewController), and the scroll view is paginated, which scrolls vertically. The cells act as different screens and you swipe vertically to move between them.

In the top cell, I have a tableview which acts as a chat log (chatLogTableView and chatLogTableViewController), so it gets long enough to need to scroll as well. When you scroll up beyond `contentOffset = 0`, I still want the content to bounce.

When you scroll to the bottom past the content of the chat log, I want to resign the chatlog as the active scroll view and instead be scrolling the parent tableView, in order to navigate between screens. If you scroll down and back up in one drag, I'm okay having the parentScrollView be the active one, it seems more logical that way to me anyways.

I'm working with this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    CGFloat height = _tableView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat frameHeight = _tableView.bounds.size.height;

    CGFloat contentOffset = _tableView.contentOffset.y;

    if (contentOffset > height - frameHeight){

        // DO SOMETHING HERE THAT STOPS THIS AS THE 
        // ACTIVE SCROLL VIEW AND SWITCH TO THE PARENT SCROLLVIEW
    }
}
```

The last key note here is that since the parentScrollView is actually a tableView, I'd prefer not to change its delegate from the fullScreenTableViewController to the chatLogTableViewController or vice versa, as this would clutter the logic, though of course I'm open to it if it has to be done.

Any suggestions? I've tried, `[scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO]`, `[_parentScrollView becomeFirstResponder]` (which I know shouldn't work, but still trying anything at this point), and I tried looking into hitTest to switch UIViews on drag, but I can't seem to find the right solution.